# Is it possible to download a complete directory from the server in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch, nsdata, nsdocumentdirectory

I am developing an app where I have to download a complete directory. This directory will contain for example:

```
article1/index.html
        /images/image1.png
               /image2.png
               /image3.png...
```

I have tried to download this, but I only can download the index.html.

I am using this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
    NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://localhost:8888/";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray   *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/issue/article%@/", documentsDirectory,articleID];

        NSLog(@"filepath: %@", filePath);
        //saving is done on main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];
            NSLog(@"File Saved !");
        });
    }

});
```

If anyone has an idea. Let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're only getting `index.html` is because this is what the web server is serving you when you request that directory. If there is no `index.html` page, it will probably give you a directory listing - however, this is usually in HTML format and you would have to manually extract the file names from this output.

If you don't have access to this web server, your job is much harder - if you can get an HTML directory listing, you'll have to parse it yourself; if not, you can't retrieve the directory list at all. In this case, it seems like you do have access to the web server, which is great! You can make this task a lot easier for yourself...

#### Option one

If the data isn't likely to change, you can create a simple text document in the root directory like `filelist.txt` that contain a list of files/paths in the directory. Your app can first request this list, separate the entries and then start downloading each file.

#### Option two

You could create a [simple web script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) (in something like PHP or your language of choice) that lists the current directory contents in a format that can be easily digested by your app - JSON, newline-separated, or anything else.

#### Option three

Package the directory contents in a .zip file, and have your app download and extract the archive. [ZipArchive](https://github.com/mattconnolly/ZipArchive) is one library that allows you to unzip files in Objective-C, and there's an easy tutorial on how to do this available on [iCodeBlog](http://www.icodeblog.com/2012/08/13/unzipping-files-using-zip-archive/).

Also, as a side note, I see you're using `NSDocumentDirectory` for downloaded content. Apple advises that the Documents folder should only be used for **user-generated** content, which does not include downloaded content. You should use `NSCachesDirectory` or `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` for data that your app downloads (note that you may have to create them first).